# Angular 2. How can I replace or include component into text

Tags: javascript, replace, typescript, angular, dynamic-loading

Situation - I've simple component:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'body',
    template: 'Body: {{ body }}'
})

export class PostBodyComponent {
    @Input('body') body: string;
}
```

And I want to replace some substrings inside body with other angular component, for example 'body' could contain some link and I want to replace this "link" with some LinkComponent. Means I need to show body with already dynamically loaded component instead of this link. Is it possible to do this somehow to show result with dynamically loaded component inside?

Comment: Can't you just use normal child component as your "link" `<link-component></link-component>`?

Comment: Currently no, I receive this data from other service

Answer (score 1):

You can't create components or directives with dynamically inserted HTML. What you can use instead is [DynamicComponentLoader](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/DynamicComponentLoader-class.html) to add/remove components imperatively

Comment: But how to use it in such situation? Remark: I receive data from external service

Comment: That's a bit vague. You can prepare components and choose one of the components to add depending of data passed in. For more detailed instructions I would need more details about your requirements.

Comment: ok. I receive from other service some text data, for example: 
{"body": "blablabla this is link http://google.com and other, other, other"}
I've already prepared LinkComponent and I need show this body to user, but instead of "http://google.com" I want to show my LinkComponent.

Comment: See `loadIntoLocation(...)` in the DynamicComponentLoader link I posted in my answer. There are still several limitations currently like data binding not being supported between host component and dynamically inserted component. There are lots of questions with answers and examples here on StackOverflow for how to use DCL.